# Ubuntu won't boot after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade

I have dualbooted with ubuntu and windows 7 but lately when i upgraded my ubuntu version from 14.04 to 14.10 i am not able to boot. When i try to go in ubuntu it starts loading normally then all this white writing appears too fast for anyone to read and then the screen just goes black and stays like that until i shutdown.

EDIT: i have tried boot repair and nothing happened D:

Comment: have you tried using the [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool?

Comment: no ill try it out

Comment: i fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu :D